# what is so bad about not using classes while creating applications in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3

Why would it be better to use classes while programming in ASE than just using object oriented programming? Can you give me some good real world sittuations of when you should use classes? I'm asking this question because I want to better understand why I should use classes in flash apps I'm going to make and am making.

Comment: How would you be using OOP without classes (which are actually prototypes in ActionScript)? Are you talking about using the ECMAScript features of ActionScript instead?

Comment: I'm not sure Bov, all I know is I don't create any classes while programming, and would like to know what's better than just using actionscript code on frames... if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using AS code on frames, you're not using object oriented programming per-se, you're just running procedural scripts affecting objects.

The advantages for flash are the same for any other class-based OOP paradigm:

- Separation of code into understandable hierarchy
- "easy" code reuse
- All design patterns that are associated with OOP
- inheritance and extension

(for more just google "advantages of Object Oriented Programming")

I find that the advantages of OOP don't seem to make a difference during the first iteration. You're writing the same essential code either way. The advantage really comes out in the second or third similar project where you can start to reuse stuff that you made before, tweak a few parameters, extend a few classes, and have a different looking flash program without rewriting *all* the code.

If you make enough projects, eventually you'll find yourself with a library or framework of classes that you can easily reuse to make very powerful applications.

Comment: Thanks Bov, this has helped me a lot!